# How to access the interest points in Harries Corner detection c#

Tags: c#, emgucv

i'm implementing Harries Corner detector using Emgucv
and i've converted the Code to C# 
using this link

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html
So i want to access the coordinates of those corners or any information about this interest points
how to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a threshold image of the Harris Corner Image and then iterate over it. This way were the intensity of the point is 255 you have a corner point whit X and Y values on the image. Example:

```
    // create corner strength image and do Harris
    m_CornerImage = new Image<Gray, float>(m_SourceImage.Size);
        CvInvoke.cvCornerHarris(m_SourceImage, m_CornerImage, 3, 3, 0.01);

        // create and show inverted threshold image
        m_ThresholdImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(m_SourceImage.Size);
        CvInvoke.cvThreshold(m_CornerImage, m_ThresholdImage, 0.0001, 255.0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        imageBox2.Image = m_ThresholdImage;
        imageBox1.Image = m_CornerImage;

        const double MAX_INTENSITY = 255;
        int contCorners = 0; 
        for (int x = 0; x < m_ThresholdImage.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < m_ThresholdImage.Height; y++)
            {
                Gray imagenP = m_ThresholdImage[y,x];
                if (imagenP.Intensity == MAX_INTENSITY)
                {
                    //X and Y are harris point cordenates 
                }
            }
        }
```